# Assiging sub string from std::string to a c-style string

Tags: c++, string

I am aware that there are ways of converting from std::string to c-style but the problem I'm having is this error: 
    4   IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
can anyone tell me what the problem is?  Also can you please clarify how to effectively convert to a c-style string and assign it in this particular case?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Addition
{
private:
    int num1[255], num2[255], sum[255];
    char str1[255], str2[255];
    string str;
    int len1, len2;
public:
    Addition(){};
    void m_add();
};

void Addition::m_add()
{
    scanf("%s", str);
    int pos = find(str[0], str[255], ' ');
    &str1 = str.substr(0, pos);
    &str2 = str.substr(++pos);
    //scanf("%s", &str1);
    //scanf("%s", &str2);
    /*convert from a character to an int*/
    for (len1 = 0; str1[len1] != '\0'; len1++)
    {
        num1[len1] = str1[len1] - '0';
    }
    for (len2 = 0; str2[len2] != '\0'; len2++)
    {
        num2[len2] = str2[len2] - '0';
    }
    if (str1 <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input\n";
    }
    int carry = 0;
    int k = 0; //keeps track of index loop stopped at
    //start adding from the end of the array
    int idx1 = len1 - 1;
    int idx2 = len2 - 1;
    //adds only for the size of teh smallest array
    for (; idx1 >= 0 && idx2 >= 0; idx1--, idx2--, k++)
    {
        //we will have to read values stored in sum in reversed order
        sum[k] = (num1[idx1] + num2[idx2] + carry) % 10;
        //using truncation to our benefit
        //carry over can only ever be one thats why we use /10 not %10
        carry = (num1[idx1] + num2[idx2] + carry) / 10;
    }
    /*takes care of the digits not added to sum from bigger array*/
    //if the first array is bigger...
    if (len1 > len2)
    {
        while (idx1 >= 0){
            sum[k++] = (num1[idx1] + carry) % 10;
            carry = (num1[idx1--] + carry) / 10;
        }
    }
    //if the second array is bigger
    else if (len1 < len2)
    {
        while (idx2 >= 0){
            sum[k++] = (num2[idx2] + carry) % 10;
            carry = (num2[idx2--] + carry) / 10;
        }
    }
    //that you have a carry ove to the very end of the number
    if (carry != 0){
        sum[k++] = carry;
    }

    cout << "sum = ";
    //print out digits in 'sum' array from back to front
    for (k--; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        cout << sum[k];
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
int main(){

    Addition inst1;
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        inst1.m_add();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The class string has a function c_str() to convert.

Comment: `scanf("%s", str);` is bad because `%s` calls for `char*` and `str` is `string`. `find(str[0], str[255], ' ');` may be bad because `str[255]` may be out-of-range. `&str1 = str.substr(0, pos);` and `&str2 = str.substr(++pos);` are bad because `&str1` and `&str2` are just address values, not variables, and the compiler won't know where to store the data.

Comment: @MartinZabel Then, use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()` (safer) to store the data to the arrays. To use them, add `#include <cstring>` to the code.

Comment: Note: `scanf("%s", &str1);` is also bad because `%s` calls for `char*` and `&str1` has type `char (*)[255]`. You should use `scanf("%s", str1);` instead of this. The same things can be said about `scanf("%s", &str2);`.

Comment: `if (str1 <= 0)` is bad because `str1` is a pointer and this comparison seems meaningless.

Comment: Although you want to deal with C strings, your question is not about the C language, it is strictly a C++ question.  I shall removed the `c` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt this is what you want to really do, but since you asked...

You need to do a `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(str1, str.substr(0, pos).c_str());
```

Review man page/cppreference for strcpy for what the parameters are.

Safer may be to use `strncpy` but that function is not actually meant to do what people use it for.  Unfortunately I don't believe there actually is a standard function in either C++ or C that does a C-style string copy limited by length...no safe `strcpy`.  The `strncpy` function does in a pinch but review the docs on that one too because it's actually meant for an entirely different string format than null-terminated, c-style strings.

It might be tempting to use `c_str()` on the `substr` return but this could be dangerous if the function you call is attempting to store a pointer to that space.  The return of `substr` will be destroyed after the call is done.  This will destroy the `c_str` return.

Comment: 'cin >> str;
 int pos = find(str[0], str[255], ' ');
 string tempstr = str.substr(0, pos);
 strcpy_s(str1, tempstr.c_str());
 tempstr = str.substr(++pos);
 strcpy(str2, tempstr.c_str());'

Comment: @AniekanUmoren Didn't know `strcpy_s` was added.  Was about to say it's common but not standard.  You're making extra copies by assigning to tempstr.  It shouldn't be necessary to do this because temporaries will last through the function call unless you're calling across threads...and you're not.  The C++ thread api in fact takes care of the only likely situation I can think of (starting thread with the copy call).